# RabbitMQ: Ubuntu 12.04 rabbitmq cannot start with firewall

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq

I was unable to start the rabbitmq on ubuntu 12.04 with firewall turn on, but in 10.04 it is ok. I have already opened the port 5672, 4639, and the inet_kernel port for erlang.

If I turn off the firewall, it is fine.

Anyone know why?

I just based on [this guide](http://marcqualie.com/2012/12/install-rabbitmq-on-ubuntu-12.04)
but it should be fine.

The error is that

```
{error_logger,{{2013,4,18},{3,53,6}},"Protocol: ~p: register error: ~p~n",["inet_tcp",{{badmatch,{error,epmd_close}},[{inet_tcp_dist,listen,1},{net_kernel,start_protos,4},{net_kernel,start_protos,3},{net_kernel,init_node,2},{net_kernel,init,1},{gen_server,init_it,6},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2013,4,18},{3,53,6}},crash_report,[[{initial_call,{net_kernel,init,['Argument__1']}},{pid,<0.20.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,{error,badarg},[{gen_server,init_it,6},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}},{ancestors,[net_sup,kernel_sup,<0.9.0>]},{messages,[]},{links,[#Port<0.90>,<0.17.0>]},{dictionary,[{longnames,false}]},{trap_exit,true},{status,running},{heap_size,610},{stack_size,24},{reductions,510}],[]]}
{error_logger,{{2013,4,18},{3,53,6}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,net_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,{'EXIT',nodistribution}},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{name,net_kernel},{mfargs,{net_kernel,start_link,[[rabbitmqprelaunch21856,shortnames]]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,2000},{child_type,worker}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2013,4,18},{3,53,6}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,kernel_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,shutdown},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{name,net_sup},{mfargs,{erl_distribution,start_link,[]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,infinity},{child_type,supervisor}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2013,4,18},{3,53,6}},std_info,[{application,kernel},{exited,{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}},{type,permanent}]}
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,kernel,{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting? What if you try to just run $ rabbitmq-server from the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell there are a few things that might be preventing it from working; If you have any anti-virus software running on your machine you'll have to open the ports within that program too (a common oversight), or maybe you've missed something is preventing the use of RabbitMQ?

If you're unsure about the firewall settings and configuration, then perhaps view the [official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/firewall.html). The most useful explanation of installing RabbitMq on Ubuntu IMHO is in [this tutorial](http://www.theprogrammer.co.za/wordpress/2012/08/installing-rabbitmq-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/)